# cancan/cantango losing user/user_session and/or roles after first request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

Vanilla authlogic/cantango setup, testing with a hard-coded `roles_list` during test that returns `[:user]`. Test permissions.yml file:

```
roles:
  user:
    can:
      manage:
      - User
```

On the first request, `user_can?(:manage, User)` does what I expect. On subsequent requests, however, it's no longer true, and my permission goes away.

<strike>The `current_user` and `current_user_session` vars change on each request; not sure if that's because I'm in dev environment and something's being reloaded, but it sketches me out a little bit.</strike> Duh :/

Implementation in `ApplicationController` follows default authlogic examples.

If I load up the console:

```
pry(main)> u = User.first
=> #<User id: 2, email: "ohai@wtf.com", [...]
pry(main)> a = CanTango::Ability.new u
=> [lots of stuff, available on request]
pry(main)> a.can?(:manage, User.new)
=> true
pry(main)> a.can?(:manage, User.new)
=> true
```

<strike>I attempted to turn cantango's caching off (just in case) in cantango.rb per cantango's docs [...]></strike>

Any hints/tips/pointers/source/docs?

Comment: _More info:_ cantango currently believes the method `current_user` is not available to it, so is calling the guest user hook. The guest user still returns the same list of roles, though, so the original problem still exists, although now I have another one. This question-asking process is working backwards so far.

Comment: _More info:_ The cantango docs for turning off caching are incorrect. With the caching turned off the guest user roles work (unsurprisingly, really). However, cantango still believes the current_user helper method in the application controller doesn't exist.

Comment: _More info:_ The perils of pasting; my application controller's helper method was private; changing it to protected made that issue go away. Now cantango isn't instantiating my guest user (although it shouldn't be, at the moment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I change the permissions.yml file to the following (these are roles, not users, in theory, but w/o the guest role, which I never reference anywhere in my code, it doesn't work) things mostly work.

```
roles:
  user:
    can:
      manage:
      - User
  guest:
    cannot:
      manage:
      - User
```

I still have to leave caching off so far.

I'm abandoning cantango for now; while I have significant role-based permissions needs, the amount of trouble this caused isn't worth it, and so far it seems like a more targeted solution using some of the same meta-techniques will be cleaner and easier.